# Find the following limit,

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]

I know $\lim_{x\to \infty } $$(\frac{2n+1}{2n-1})$ $^{(n-1)}$=$e$

and

$\lim_{x\to \infty } $ $ ({3n^{2016}-1})^\frac1n$= 1

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. One may observe that, for $n\ge1$,
$$
\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}} \le \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}} \le \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}
$$
gives
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}} \le \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}}.
$$